# minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB3: Device or resource busy

Tags: minicom

i have quectel EC 25 modem in my pc. i am using ubuntu 16.04 OS.
while using minicom it showing this minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB3: Device or resource busy error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use `minicom` with `sudo`.
2. Add your user to the `dialout` group by

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER
   ```

Logout and login. After that you'll be able to reach your modem without `sudo`.